# Trying to send a value from JS to PHP - JQuery's $.ajax() method is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I want to execute a JS function when a PHP form is submitted, and from that function, I want to return a value (which is based on user's input) to PHP, where I'd like to echo it.

This is an SSCCE. In the real code, there is more than just echoing the value, and the value is a JSON object.

Following is my code. **The problem is that the `$.ajax();` part is not working. Nothing happens in the browser after `alert(name);`. 
Why isn't this working properly? How can I fix this?**

**From index.php:**

```
<form id="form">
  Name:
  <input id="name" type="text" />
  <input type="Submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

**From scripts.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var name = $("#name").val();
        alert(name);

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'echo.php',
            data: {
                nameEntered : name
            }
        });

    });

});
```

**echo.php:**

```
<?php  
if (    isset($_POST["nameEntered"]) && !empty($_POST["nameEntered"])    ) {
    echo $_POST["nameEntered"];
} else {
    echo '$_POST["nameEntered"] is not set.';
}
?>
```

---

***EDIT:***

Console:

[image]

Network:

[image]

---

***EDIT 2:***

Added the following to `$.ajax()`:

```
,
success: function(){
    alert("success");
},
error : function(){ 
    alert("error");
}
```

**I get an alert saying `success` but the browser NEVER directs to echo.php =s**

---

***EDIT 3:***

After the alert saying `success`, a `?` is added to the URL in the browser. Initially the URL was `http://localhost/Test12/index.php` and it changed to `http://localhost/Test12/index.php?`.

Comment: what error do you see in console ?

Comment: And in the console you see? And __nothing__ would happen as you don't define `success` callback.

Comment: He can still see the php output from the response page. Just nothing in JS. Did you include jQuery library on the page before your script?

Comment: @Poria Console is empty..

Comment: At least in a console should be warning about `event not defined`

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc No, the browser does NOT go to `echo.php`

Comment: Is there a network request in the network panel? Because that's the only thing that's going to happen with your code. You're not *doing* anything with the AJAX response. It has no success handler.

Comment: @u_mulder No nothing in the console. Posting screenshot in question

Comment: Not the console, the network panel.

Comment: submit(function() {   here event is missing submit(function(event) {

Comment: @ceejayoz Added a screenshot to the question

Comment: @u_mulder Added a screenshot to the question

Comment: okay is it working --  alert(name);  ??

Comment: @ceejayoz [This page](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/#success-callback) says `success` is _optional_?

Comment: @u_mulder [This page](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/#success-callback) says `success` is _optional_?

Comment: Are you sure javascript is enabled?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc Ofcourse. That's why I am getting the alerts

Comment: @ceejayoz Please see my last edit in the question? I think it is some clue.

Comment: @u_mulder Please see my last edit in the question? I think it is some clue.

Comment: @Poria Yes the alert was working. Added a couple edits to the question after that.

Comment: by just doing this submit(function() { here event is missing submit(function(event) { ajax is firing with the parameter nameEntered here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fdn72z3f/1/

Comment: @Poria How do you know AJAX is firing. There is no PHP in JSFiddle

Comment: i see in console, the problem is with file path you are requesting because i see the php code is fine

Comment: @Poria All the files are in the same folder. I also tried to give full absolute path to the `url` in `$.ajax()`. Can you try it on your machine?

Comment: There  is not a single problem with your code except the file path you are calling and the "event" missing.

It is working fine on my machine.

Comment: Maybe it's a permissions issue? Can you run your PHP script without an ajax call to it? Like access it in your browser directly, like at `localhost/echo.php` ?

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc I can access it directly in browser

Comment: Is it solved yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test, replace your `echo.php` with:

```
<?php  
    echo 'Incoming = ' .$_POST["nameEntered"]. "/r/n";

    if (isset($_POST["nameEntered"]) && !empty($_POST["nameEntered"])) {
        echo 'Here 01';
    } else {
        echo 'Here 02';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I changed `echo 'Here 01';` to `echo $_POST["nameEntered"];` and I get the correct value in the alert. This works. Someone in the answers had previously said that I had to use `return` statement instead of `echo`. I was doing that. But I guess I did not have to do that. Thank you so, so very much

Answer (score 2):

This way should show response.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#name").val();
    //alert(name);

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://localhost/Test12/echo.php',
        data: {
            nameEntered : name
        },
        success : function(data){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        },
        error : function(error){
            console.log('erro', error);
        }
    });

});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php  

if (isset($_POST["nameEntered"]) && !empty($_POST["nameEntered"])) {
    $name = array("nome" => $_POST["nameEntered"]);
    echo json_encode($name);
} else {
    echo '$_POST["nameEntered"] is not set.';
}
?>
```

Comment: I did this. Console is still empty, which has added to the confusion. Also, [this page](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/#success-callback) says `success` is _optional_?

Comment: Is optional, but you need a promisse, to say if your request fail or give success, maybe not the success function, but a done function at least, if still empty the console, the problem maybe is in the php file

Comment: OK I removed `data` and `error` arguments from the functions you added, and changed `console.log()` statements to `alert("success");` and `alert("error");` statements respectively. I got the alert saying "success". But this browser NEVER directs to `echo.php` =s

Comment: So the error is inside your php file, because if u got a success, that mean you comunicate the js to your server

Comment: The "echo.php" are in the same folder or path?

Comment: Well yes they are in the same folder

Comment: So try use your path url:"localhost/mypath/echo.php", or something like this

Comment: Doesn't work. Hey no offense but are you making blind guesses?

Comment: Please see my last edit in the question? I think it is some clue.

Comment: I`m not making blind guesses, the error are in the url, you need specify the url where are your php file, so the ajax can send a request, and php return a response, so every change in code you need look to your network tab, to see if your app send a request to the right path.
You are running a server right?

Comment: Network tab remains empty. Could you try it on your machine?

Comment: I make some changes, but here work's, i'll edit my answer, please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the document.ready() or instead of .submit use .on('submit', function(e){}); or add absolute path '/page.php'

Comment: Changing `.submit` to ` .on('submit', function(e){});` didn't change anything. Removing `document.ready()` results in reloading of page as soon as submit is clicked

Comment: What about adding the absolute path?

Comment: Try adding only a slash '/page' in case you tried the full path else last option, probably wont make a difference but have you tried setting cache to false and putting quotes around nameEntered in the js file?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add "event" as parameter in your submit function, in addition to the success call to show results

Comment: Did that. No luck.

Comment: so I can't comment on other answers, but did you try adding JSON.stringify({
                nameEntered : name
            })

Answer (score 1):

What does this give you:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'echo.php',
    data: {
        nameEntered : name
    },
    success: function(recd){   // <-------
        alert(recd);           // <-------
    },
    error : function(){ 
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Comment: An alert having a blank string

Comment: Aha! That tells you something - the data being echo'd out from PHP is also blank. See new test in separate answer.

Comment: "the data being echo'd out from PHP is also blank" - No someone in the answers had said that I have to use `return` instead of `echo`. I was using return statement in echo.php

Answer (score 0):

You're calling event.preventDefault(), but you've failed to add the event to your callback's parameters... so you're not actually stopping the form from being submitted. That is why you see the question mark in the address bar.

Try:

```
function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: No I added it later. Lemme reflect it in question. Should already have, My bad